# Virtual machine created from a dd image of a NUC machine doesn't start Xorg

Tags: xorg, vmware

I created a `dd if=/dev/sda` image on an NUC running a possibly customized Ubuntu 15.04. The NUC has 2 GB RAM, 16 GB SSD and runs on Intel Celeron 1037U.

I created a new virtual hard disk and `dd`'d the image to that virtual hard disk in another running system, and then created a new virtual machine on this restored virtual hard disk.

The problem I'm having is, the virtual machine does not start normally and gets stuck at this screen. The `Last login` line updates every 15 seconds. By examining `$HOME/.profile`, it seems it's stuck at this line:

```
exec startx &> ~/.xsession-errors
```

Checking the logs it appears like that the display (screen / monitor) has changed and Xorg doesn't work with that, but I am not 100% sure.

> [image: mmm]

Here's the tail of the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    54.521] (++) using VT number 1
[    54.521] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[    54.521] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[    54.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    54.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    54.521] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    54.521] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    54.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    54.521] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    54.521]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.0.2
[    54.521]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    54.521] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    54.521] (EE) No devices detected.
[    54.521] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    54.521] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    54.521] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    54.521] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    54.521] (EE)
```

Note: I am able to attach this virtual disk to another VM and `chroot` into the system inside and investigate for issues. I have managed to install `open-vm-tools` after chroot-ing into the system but still same problem.

How do I boot this VM up?

Comment: while I am aware that questions about 15.04 are off-topic, I don't this one is *specific* to 15.04 and should therefore not be closed by that reason. please.

Comment: And why shouldn't it?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I said I'm confident that the problem isn't *specific* to 15.04. i.e. same issue can happen on 14.04 or 18.04, so the fact that 15.04 has reached EOL has virtually nothing to do with this question. It's related to Xorg instead.

Comment: I have a solution now

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Only questions likely specific to EoL releases (it's mentioned in the close reason).  E.g. questions where "upgrade" is the proper answer.  iBug: Unless you actually upgraded the system please don't edit the version numbers in your post. It only makes you look worse. Thanks.  I've reopened this question for now.  Did you look in `~.xsession-errors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours hard work Googling this problem, I found [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=223581) that contained information that help me solve the problem.

Just move the Xorg configuration file (to save it as a backup) and reboot:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg-old.conf
```

Then Xorg will try to detect any new devices.